# Spring cron expression every after 30 minutes

Tags: spring, cron, expression

Java spring - I have following cron expression for cron job.

```
0 0/35 * * * ?
```

But above mentioned cron expression fires once in an hour and like as follows

1:35
2:35
3:35
4:35

I want to fire every after 35 mins instead once in an hour

any quick suggestion ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cron syntax is

```
sec min hour day day_of_month month day_of_week year
```

So what you would want is

```
0 0,35 * * * * ?
```

So it will fire on minutes 0 and 35 of each hour.

See the [Quartz docs](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-1.x/tutorials/crontrigger) for this, as Spring is using Quartz as scheduler here. Those docs also explain the special chars like * ? - , and others.

Comment: You are of course right - I read the "1:35 2:35 3:35 4:35" as the requirement

Answer (score 2):

You have specified an increment instead of two values.

There is no minute `35 + 35 = 70`.
Replace `0/35` with `0,35`.

Comment: Because I am stupid. (See my answer to your question on my answer). I have flagged it as "inform moderator" to cancel my downvote, as I can't cancel it myself.

Comment: No, unfortunately I can't - it gives me a message that this is not possible - unless the answer is edited.

Comment: Yes, that helped - sorry again.

Comment: Thanks. So we can safely delete all comments now. :)