# How to run a job from 20.35 until 23.35 every 30 minutes, some days a week?

Tags: java, cron, cronexpression

I am facing a problem with cron expression.
I have to ran a method from Thursday to Sunday by every 30 minutes. It time will start from 20:35 min till 23:35 min.

Cron expression:

```
"0 35/30 20-23 ? * THU-SUN";
```

As per my understanding; My method will invoke at 20:35 min at Thursday by every 30 minutes till Sunday.

My Expectation:

Method will invoke as per below timings:

```
Thu May 19 20:35:00 IST 2016
Thu May 19 21:05:00 IST 2016
Thu May 19 21:40:00 IST 2016
```

But;  Method get invokes by below timings:

```
Thu May 19 20:35:00 IST 2016
Thu May 19 21:35:00 IST 2016
Thu May 19 22:35:00 IST 2016
```

Can anyone help me out. Why cron expression evaluating by every 1 hour.??

Here is code example:

```
@Scheduled(cron="0 35/30 20-23 ? * THU-SUN")
  public void startInboundSFTPChannel(){
      logger.info("Cron job started....");
      downloadSftpFilesController();
  }
```

Comment: You should tell us how your cron expression is used (add some code maybe?)

Comment: Isn't be easier to use: `"0 5,35 20-23 ? * THU-SUN";`?

Comment: Hi RC..I added some code parts. Please check.

Comment: Hi @tommus, This cron expression will not work. Because it will start every 05 and 35 min from 8 to 11 Pm.

Comment: so you want it to start a 20.35 Thursday and run every 30 min all days and hours until Sunday at 23.35 or every day in this time range?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the command to run from 20.35 to 23.35 every day, from Thursday to Sunday, you can define it in two steps:

```
35   20    ? * THU-SUN
5-59 21-23 ? * THU-SUN
```

There is no easy way to set this up in just a cron expression, because you don't want it to run at 20.05.

That is: at 20 , run at the minute 35. At 21 to 23 h, [every 30 minutes with an offset of 5 minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19204734/1983854).

---

I based my answer on this format:

```
 +---------------- minute (0 - 59)
 |  +------------- hour (0 - 23)
 |  |  +---------- day of month (1 - 31)
 |  |  |  +------- month (1 - 12)
 |  |  |  |  +---- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0 or 7)
 |  |  |  |  |
 *  *  *  *  *  command to be executed
```

Comment: got you. Thanks. If I start from 20:35 min and add 30 min in time then its addition will be 65. which will be greater that (0-59). That's why my cron expression is not evaluating properly.

Comment: @Kumar yes, exactly. You can always evaluate your cron expressions in http://crontab.guru/

Comment: Thanks buddy.. @fedorqui

Comment: Yep @fedorqui. I have to modify cron expression. By which minutes should not exceed than 59.

Answer (score 2):

As I understand, your expression (`0 35/30 20-23 ? * THU-SUN`) means:

- `0` - run at full minute only,
- `35/30` - run every 30 minutes starts from 35,
- `20-23` - run hours between 20 and 23,
- `?` - use implicit days from later part of expression,
- `*` run at every single month,
- `THU-SUN` - run at Thursday, Friday, Saturday and Sunday.

So, as you specified an increment instead of two values [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/) (which Spring uses) tries to calulate this like the following:

- first, it calculates the value `35` for minutes - what matches `0-59` condition,
- second, it adds `30` to previous `35` (which equals `65`) what not matches `0-59` condition,
- at the end, the only correct value is `35`.

So, it runs your code every single hour when minutes == `35`.

Can you handle running the code one more time at `Thu May 19 20:05:00 IST 2016`?

If yes, then you can use one of the following expressions:

1. `0 5,35 20-23 ? * THU-SUN`

Which means:

- `0` - run at full minute only,
- `5,35` - run every 30 minutes, starting from minutes == 5,
- `20-23` - run hours between 20 and 23,
- `?` - use implicit days from later part of expression,
- `*` - run at every single month,
- `THU-SUN` - run at Thursday, Friday, Saturday and Sunday.

  2. `0 5/30 20-23 ? * THU-SUN`

Which means:

- `0` - run at full minute only,
- `5/30` - run every 30 minutes starting from minutes == 5,
- `20-23` - run hours between 20 and 23,
- `?` - use implicit days from later part of expression,
- `*` - run at every single month,
- `THU-SUN` - run at Thursday, Friday, Saturday and Sunday.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8560613/2057291) you can find similar problem.